# Return JSON string from SQL/C#

Tags: c#, json

Environment:  ASP.NET  C#  JavaScript/JQuery

My End goal is this:

```
{
"LblMonthly" :  "炒麵炒麵 炒麵 (",
"lblName": "testing#"//''""""""" ",
"lblTest": "First Name"
}
```

I make the data call to SQL and return the above 2 columns (labelName, labelValue).

Like this:

```
        public static string GetLanguage()
    {

        InnoCommonDataContext db = new InnoCommonDataContext();
        List<ps_TST_ReturnControlTitleResult> e = new List<ps_TST_ReturnControlTitleResult>();
        e = db.ps_TST_ReturnControlTitle().ToList();

        return  new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(e);

    }
```

I want that to be a string like the above request. 
I'm not sure I'm using the correct approach.

NOTE:  I do want it a string as a return.

I need to handle special characters and multiple languages.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know if this may help but check [Json](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

Comment: I am considering Json.Net.   Just thought I shouldn't need to add another framework for a simple Name/value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `DTO` class with the 3 properties (LblMonthly,
lblName, lblTest) that you want to return. Fill the `DTO` with the appropriate values and then serialize to JSON.

```
public class DTO 
{
    public string Monthly { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Test { get; set; }
}

var d = new DTO() {
    Monthly = "value1",
    Name = "value2",
    Test = "value3"
};

// Using JSON.Net
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);
```

Comment: I'm not using MVC.  The return is only Name/Value.  I am using it for control labels.  So I need Ctrl1 = 'Name',  Ctrl2 = 'Address', Ctrl3 = 'Phone'   etc.

Comment: The `json` string above will return your end goal. It doesn't have to be `MVC`. You can call the `DTO` class anything you want.